# Loading of a td value using another td value in Ember hbs file

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember hbs component, in which we have table, in which the value of a td should be decided depending upon the value of the previous td, here is my hbs code, any help please?

```
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                {{#if model.novs}}
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Notice#</th>
                                                <th>Type</th>
                                                <th>Violation</th>
                                                <th>Inspection Item</th>
                                                <th>
                                                    Action
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>                                               
                                            {{#each  model.novs as |nov index|}}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{nov.NOVNumber}}</td>
                                                <td>{{nov.NOVNoticeTypeName}} {{nov.ViolationTypeName}}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    {{#each  nov.Violations as |novv index|}}
                                                    {{novv.ViolationNumber}}
                                                    {{novv.Year}}
                                                    {{novv.Make}}
                                                    {{novv.Model}}
                                                    {{#if novv.Vin}}(VIN#:
                                                    {{novv.Vin}})
                                                    {{/if}}
                                                    <br />
                                                    {{/each}}
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    {{#each  model.result.items as |novi index|}}
                                                    {{novi.itemNum}}
                                                    <br />
                                                    {{/each}}
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    {{#if isResCompletedStatus}}
                                                    <div class="btn btn-xs btn-default" onclick={{action "editNov" nov.NOVId}}>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                                                        View Notice
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="btn btn-xs btn-default" onclick={{action "generatePreCase" nov.NOVId }}>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
                                                        Generate Investigation
                                                    </div>
                                                    {{else}}
                                                    <div class="btn btn-xs btn-default" onclick={{action "editNov" nov.NOVId}}>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                        Edit Notice
                                                    </div>
                                                    {{/if}}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            {{/each}}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                {{else}}
                                    {{#unless isResCompletedStatus}}
                                        {{#link-to 'result.details.nov.details' 0 disabled=isResFormDisabledBoolean}}
                                            <div class="well text-center no-margin">
                                                Click here to add a Notice.
                                            </div>
                                        {{/link-to}}
                                        {{else}}
                                        <div class="well text-center no-margin">
                                            No notices...
                                        </div>
                                    {{/unless}}
                                {{/if}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

In the above code, the model.result.items has Violation element, how can I display the novi.itemNum for the novv.ViolationNumber that is displayed, any help please - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on your question, but I think you are looking to filter one collection (`model.result.items`) by a value (`novv.ViolationNumber`). If that is the case, you could use [ember-composable-helpers#find-by](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#filter-by).

```
<td>
  {{#with (find-by 'ViolationNumber' novv.ViolationNumber model.result.items) as |item|}}
    {{log item}}
  {{/with}}
</td>
```